# What is the fastest way to go from Warsaw to Moscow via Lithuania and Latvia by bus/train?

Tags: trains, buses, russia, poland, moscow

I will start from Dresden (Germany). I definitely want to visit Poland, and especially Warsaw. Then I have to go to Moscow to catch the train to Beijing, and I have to bypass Belarus.

So what is the fastest way to go from Poland to Moscow via Lithuania and Latvia by bus or train?

Comment: Better!  You can delete your original question to prevent its forced closure; it's recommended

Comment: I always drove, but for absolute sure the train from Kaliningrad has GOT to be a contender.  Even if you have to go there to board.  It's got to be right up there if not the fastest.

Comment: @GayotFow it does stop in Belarus: http://railroad.mobiticket.ru/traintt.php?train_n=030%D0%A7%D0%90&seq_n=5&station_from=2058001&station_to=2000006&show_costs=true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Train travel between Poland, Lithuania and Latvia is currently very cumbersome. The following thread may be relevant for this:

[Are there trains beween Tallinn, Riga and Warsaw?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13460/are-there-trains-beween-tallinn-riga-and-warsaw)

This means that you should go by bus. As an example, Lux Express, has a daily departure to Vilnius, from where you can proceed to Riga. Currently, the bus leaves Warsaw at 18:25 and arrives in Riga at 15:25 the following day. This will leave you a 2 hours buffer in Riga. Note that the bus and railway stations there are next to each other. This way, Warsaw-Moscow will take you **about 40 hours**.

However, if you want to bypass Belarus, you have another option: going by train via Kyïv. There is a direct night train from Warsaw to Kyïv, and there are direct trains from Kyïv to Moscow. Currently you can leave Warsaw at 16:50 and arrive in Moscow at 4:32 two days later, after a journey of **nearly 35 hours**, with a change of trains in Kyïv. Another possibility is to travel via Lviv. This option may be interesting if  you also want to visit Krakow or other places in southeastern Poland.

Comment: Assuming you do not want to fly (definitely fastest), there are many buses driven by different companies, so either you go via Kiev or Vilnius - you'll have a choice.

Answer (score 7):

As I understood from your original question, you think that you can't use a train because of lack of the Belarus visa, but you can get the transit Belarus visa, and with it you can get to the Moscow in **18 hours**! with [train Warshaw - Moscow](http://pass.rzd.ru/static/public/ru?STRUCTURE_ID=5125&layer_id=3290&refererLayerId=3290&id=2025) (in Russian, [live timetable in English can be found here](http://pass.rzd.ru/timetable/public/en?STRUCTURE_ID=735)).

If this is still not an option for you, why bothering youself with bus trip for more than day, if you can get from Lithuania or Latvia by other trains (even faster than from Warshaw):

- [LDZ train](http://ldz.lv/en) from Riga ([in Russian](http://pass.rzd.ru/static/public/ru?STRUCTURE_ID=5125&layer_id=3290&id=2369), [in English](http://travel.ldz.lv/en/ldz/vilciena-kustibas)) in **16 hours**
- <strike>[JSC Lithuanian railways](http://www.litrail.lt/en) train from Vilnius ([in Russian](http://pass.rzd.ru/static/public/ru?STRUCTURE_ID=5125&layer_id=3290&id=2370), [live timetable in English](http://www.litrail.lt/en/keleiviams)) in **15 hours**</strike> this is with transit via Belarus.
- Train from Tallinn with transit in St.-Petersburg ([in Russian](http://pass.rzd.ru/static/public/ru?STRUCTURE_ID=5125&layer_id=3290&refererLayerId=3290&id=2266)) not so fast, but still an option if you want to visit "northern capital" of Russia (in this case you should but a ticket only to St.-Petersburg, and after that use a numerous night trains to Moscow.

I do not suggest you to choose the bus as the roads in Russia, especially far from capital, not very good for you, believe me ;)